# Close login form after opening FormMain (MDI)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a login form linked to database, when the login is successful it opens my `FormMain` which is a MDI form.

I have this code in my Program.cs:

```
FormLogin formLogin = new FormLogin();
if (formLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Application.Run(new FormMain());
}
else
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

What I would like to achieve is, Once the `FormMain` is opened it should close the login form. At the moment after the main form is opened you can alt tab and go to the login form again. I have tried adding `formLogin.Close();` before `Application.Run....` without success.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you're showing the login form then the application is already running, no?

Comment: Have You tried formLogin.Show()? (rest code same)

Comment: I'm assuming @M.Babcock is correct. Likely you want to show your FormMain, not try to run it as an application. Your "application" is already running because that is what is displaying your login form.

Comment: If you set `DialogResult` of your `FormLogin` to `OK` which result in opening your `FormMain` so `FormLogin` should be closed now. You should share a simple code which reproduces the problem. Currently the code doesn't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given the way this is implemented you can hide the login form although it may be possible to close it in another method given the way you currently have it. Another option is to open the main form in a new thread and close the current thread. this will completely close the login page and pass all control to the only active thread. also, please note. if you are using threads then the main form cannot be a child thread